# What is causing tip dieback of Norway Spruce?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, plant-health, soil, tree-care

This is a recently planted Norway Spruce in Mount Horeb, Wisconsin. 1/3 planted trees is experiencing tip dieback. Is this planting stress, symptom of a tip blight, or something else?

[image: full tree]

[image: tip dieback]

Comment: Is this just on one side of your tree?

Comment: Down from a road? How large it is such road? Could salt be a problem?

Comment: It is spotty around the whole tree. Down from the road with some salt, but many other spruces in area with no symptoms.

Comment: Seems likely to be a shock caused by some aspect of transplanting. I would just wait and be sure to water in dry weather. ( I spent several vacations at Blue Mounds when it was a private camp,)